# Replacing a View with a UIActivityIndicator Programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have been trying to create a quick method that will allow me to replace any UIView with a spinner right before a process starts and do the re-show the view once my process is done. For some reason, the UIView does disappear but the spinner never shows. These are the methods in question:

```
func showLoader(view: UIView, controller: UIViewController) -> UIActivityIndicatorView {

    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
    spinner.color = AC_BLUE
    spinner.center = view.center
    spinner.startAnimating()

    view.alpha = 0
    controller.view.addSubview(spinner)

    return spinner
}

func hideLoader(view: UIView, spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView) {

    view.alpha = 1
    spinner.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

..which I call with something like this:

```
let spinner = Extensions().showLoader(view: signInBtn, controller: self)

APICalls().getUser(email: usernameTextField.text!, pass: passwordTextField.text!) { success, user in

     //..CODE..//
     Extensions().hideLoader(view: self.signInBtn, spinner: spinner)

}
```

Also, I tried centering on the main VC view, and that does work. So I'm guessing it must be related to the view's position.

Thanks!

Comment: It appears you are adding the `spinner` to the view. Then you are settings the view to have an alpha of `0` which means anything that is a `subview` of the view will have an alpha of `0` as well.

Comment: No, I'm adding it to the controller's main view (aka. controller.view...)

Comment: Have you tried using the `Capture View Hierarchy`  to see if it is visible on the screen anywhere?

Comment: Check my updated answer, that works for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting this before adding the spinner to the controllers view (instead of the old `spinner.center = view.center`):

```
spinner.center = view.superview!.convert(view.center, to: controller.view)
```

You need to convert the `view`'s `center` to the coordinates of the `controller.view`.